# Can I change the Thunderbird send priority in config editor

Tags: thunderbird

I would like to have all my mails that I send to default to 'highest priority' rather than 'normal'. I have combed through the Thunderbird config but cannot see any parameter pertaining to this.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a way to do such a thing but when thunderbird being your active application if you press

```
 Ctrl+Shift+H
```

Then this should open a new email with the highest priority setting on